# Regex split paragraph by period followed by newline (Arabic Text)

Tags: java, regex, split, arabic, arabic-support

I have some arabic text which I want to split into paragraphs. I want to split on periods followed by a new line or a question mark followed by a new line or an exclamation mark followed by a new line

Here is what I tried

```
split("(\\.|؟|!)\\r\\n");
```

here is sample text 1

```
لفت نظري واستغرابي إعلانان كلاهما يتعلق بـ"طلب مرئيات العموم" من هيئة
الاتصالات وتقنية المعلومات المنشور في جميع الصحف وملخصهما أن الهيئة من أجل
الترخيص لمقدمي خدمة الهاتف الجوال أو الترخيص لمقدمي خدمة المعطيات (ولنا عودة
لهذه الكلمة) تدعو الأطراف المعنية لإبداء مرئياتهم ومنهم الراغبون بتقديم الخدمة
والهيئات الأخرى ذات العلاقة مثل الجهات الحكومية والمنشآت الصناعية والتجارية
والهيئات الأكاديمية وموردي الأجهزة ومقدمي الخدمات وأي طرف آخر من الجمهور له
اهتمام بالأمر، ويشير الإعلان إلى وثيقة ينبغي الرجوع إليها لإبداء المرئيات
موجودة في موقع الهيئة بشبكة الإنترنت التي تتضمن (24) سؤالا تتعلق بترخيص
المعطيات و(38) سؤالا تخص خدمة الجوال... ومبعث الاستغراب هو أننا لم نتعود من
الجهات الحكومية أو غيرها أن تطلب رأي أو ملاحظات العموم وهم الجمهور أو الشعب في
مشروع أو برنامج قبل تنفيذه... وهذا بظني أسلوب جديد له الكثير من الإيجابيات
يأتي في قمتها حصول الهيئة على أكثر من (62) استشارة مجانية وهي الملاحظات
والآراء التي ترد من كل طرف متجاوب من الأطراف ممن لهم مصلحة أو لهم علاقة بحكم
الاختصاص أو ممن سيستعمل المشروع أو الخدمة أو متبرع بمرئياته من الجمهور، ومما
لا شك فيه أن الهيئة ستقوم بدراسة وتمحيص ما يرد لها والأخذ بالصالح منها مما
سيمكنها من تلافي السلبيات وتعزيز الإيجابيات ومنح التراخيص المعلن عنها
للمستحقين والمؤهلين وبشروط عادلة تخدم فوق كل اعتبار المصلحة العامة...
 وتبقى ثلاثة أمور لا بد من الإشارة إليها تخص إعلان هيئة الاتصالات أولها أن
المرئيات المطلوبة من العموم هي في أغلبها نواح فنية يصعب على الناس العاديين
فهمها ناهيك عن إبداء الرأي حيالها، ومع ذلك فإن هناك أصحاب الاختصاص وربما
المصلحة من الناس الذين لا بد أن يهمهم الأمر، وثانيها أن الإعلان غير واضح من
قراءته باللغة العربية لأول وهلة وأكرر لأول وهلة... وأخص بالذكر إعلان الهيئة
الخاص بطلب مرئيات العموم عن ترخيص تقديم خدمات المعطيات... وقد احترت في فهم
"المعطيات" حتى قرأتها باللغة الإنجليزية فوجدت (وأنا لست بالمترجم المحترف) أن
الترجمة الأقرب هي خدمات إرسال أو توصيل الحزم أو البيانات الرقمية، وثالث الأمور
أن الإعلان يشير إلى وثيقة خاصة ينبغي الرجوع إليها لإبداء المرئيات... وهذه
الوثيقة موجودة باللغة الإنجليزية فقط في موقع الهيئة بشبكة الإنترنت كما نص
الإعلان وخلاصة القول إن الإعلان كان من الممكن كتابته باللغة العربية بشكل أفضل
وأوضح.
 ومع ذلك فإن لهيئة الاتصالات الفضل لكونها أو لجهة حكومية تتبع أسلوبا ديمقراطيا
(إن صح التعبير) وذا شفافية عالية سيكون له قطعا مصلحة وفائدة لمجلس إدارتها في
اتخاذ القرار المناسب عند استعراضه الخيارات المقدمة إليه من محصلة الآراء
المستلمة... ويبقى أن يتفاعل ويتجاوب أصحاب العلاقة من اختصاصيين ومستفيدين
ومستهلكين بتقديم آرائهم حتى تنجح التجربة.
 ويبقى تساؤل للعموم ربما لا يوجد جواب عليه وهو أما كان من الممكن أن تكون بعض
المشروعات والبرامج المهمة أفضل لو اتبع حيالها مثل هذا الأسلوب في أخذ مرئيات
العموم قبل تنفيذها مثل مشروعات بعض المطارات والطرق ومثل برامج كمناهج التعليم
والتدريب ومكافحة الفقر..؟ 
والأهم من هذا وذاك نقترح على مجلس الشورى قبل إقرار أي نظام له تأثير على شرائح
كبيرة من المجتمع أن ينشره كمسودة ويدعو أصحاب العلاقة والعموم لإبداء مرئياتهم
عليه للحصول على استشارات مجانية قد يكون بعضها في غاية الفائدة قبل إقراره...
فنظام مهم مثل نظام السوق المالية مع التقدير للمديح الكثير الذي تحصل عليه حتى
قبل اختباره أو تطبيقه أما كان الأفضل تلافي الكثير من السلبيات التي قد تظهر عند
التطبيق لو تم نشره كمسودة وتم أخذ مرئيات العموم من أصحاب العلاقة ومنهم المئات
أو الآلاف من المتعاملين بالأسهم ومن مرتادي غرف تداول الأسهم في فروع البنوك.
```

here is sample text 2

```
لودفيج فان بيتهوفن مؤلف موسيقي ألماني ولد عام 1770 م في مدينة بون. يعتبر من أبرز عباقرة الموسيقى في جميع العصور، وأبدع أعمالاً موسيقية خالدة. له الفضل الأعظم في تطوير الموسيقى الكلاسيكية. قدم أول عمل موسيقي وعمره 8 سنوات.
تشمل مؤلفاته للأوركسترا تسـعة سيمفونيات وخمس مقطوعات موسيقية على البيانو ومقطوعة على الكمان. كما ألّف العديد من المقطوعات الموسيقية كمقدمات للأوبرا.
بدأ بيتهوفن يفقد سمعه في الثلاثينيات من عمره إلا أن ذلك لم يؤثر على إنتاجه الذي ازداد في تلك الفترة وتميز بالإبداع. من أجمل أعماله السمفونية الخامسة والسادسة والتاسعة. وقد توفي في فيينا عام 1827م.
شهدت مدينة بون الألمانية ميلاد الفنان العبقري لودفج فان بيتهوفن في 16 ديسمبر عام 1770، وتم تعميده في 17 ديسمبر 1770. ظهر تميزه الموسيقي منذ صغره، فنشرت أولى أعماله وهو في الثانية عشرمن عمره عام 1783 م. اتسعت شهرته كعازف بيانو في سن مبكرة، ثم زاد إنتاجه وذاع صيته كمؤلف موسيقى. عانى بيتهوفن كثيراً في حياته، عائلياً وصحياً، فبالرغم من أن أباه هو معلمه الأول الذي وجه اهتمامه للموسيقى ولقنه العزف على البيانو والكمان، إلا أنه لم يكن الأب المثالي، فقد كان مدمناً للكحول، كما أن والدته توفيت وهو في السابعة عشر من عمره بعد صراع طويل مع المرض، تاركة له مسؤولية العائلة. مما منعه من إتمام خطته والسفر إلى فيينا، عاصمة الموسيقى في ذلك العصر. فهل كان التأليف الموسيقي هو نوع من أنواع العلاج والتغلب على المشاكل بالنسبة لبيتهوفن.
في 1789 م تحقق حلمه أخيراً، فقد أرسله حاكم بون إلى فيينا، وهناك تتلمذ على يد هايدن. ولكن بيتهوفن، صاحب الألحان واجه بعض الخلافات مع معلمه، وعندما سافر هايدن إلى لندن، تحول بيتهوفن إلى معلمين آخرين مثل ساليري وشينك وألبريشتبيرجر. وقد أسهمت كل هذه الدروس والاحتكاكات في تكوين شخصية بيتهوفن الفنية. وحاول أن يشق لنفسه طريق كعازف في عاصمة الموسيقى، وسرعان ما لاقى مكانة كبرى خاصة في الأوساط الأرستقراطية. فقد حاز بإعجاب الأسرة الملكية وعومل كصديق أكثر منه مؤلفاً. بالرغم من ذلك فقد عاش ومات فقيراً، غناه هو أعماله الفنية المتميزة. فقد جاء إنتاجه الفني غزيراً حتى بعد إصابته بالصمم.
بدأت إصابة بيتهوفن بصمم بسيط عام 1802، فبدأ في الانسحاب من الأوساط الفنية تدريجياً، وأمضى حياته بلا زواج يرتبط بعلاقات عدة مع سيدات صغيرات. إلا أنه لم يتوقف عن الإنتاج الفني، ولكن أعماله اتخذت اتجاه جديد. ومع ازدياد حالة الصمم التي أصابته، امتنع عن العزف في الحفلات العامة، وابتعد عن الحياة الاجتماعية واتجه للوحدة، وقلت مؤلفاته، وأصبحت أكثر تعقيداً. حتى أنه رد على انتقادات نقاده بأنه يعزف للأجيال القادمة. وبالفعل مازالت أعماله حتى اليوم من أهم ما أنتجته الموسيقى الكلاسيكية العالمية. واكتسبت اثنان من السيمفونيات التي كتبها في صممه أكبر شعبية، وهما السيمفونية الخامسة والتاسعة. كما أنه أحدث الكثير من التغييرات في الموسيقى، وأدخل الغناء والكلمات في سيمفونيته التاسعة.فجاءت رسالته إلى العالم كل البشر سيصبحون إخوة.
```

when I use this I just get the whole text as one paragraph. It doesn't even split on periods. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: there's zero newlines in any of your example text

Comment: you're right sorry how do I copy the text with the newlines into stack overflow?

Comment: @Seif You can try to put it in a code block. Anyway, try using `[\\r\\n]` instead of `\\r\\n`. Perhaps your linebreaks consist of just CR or just LF.

Comment: I just edited it for you. Feel free to make any additional changes to the linebreaks if they don't match the actual text.

Comment: @41686d6564 Still the same

Comment: @41686d6564 Thanks for the edit

Comment: @Seif It [works](https://rextester.com/OGWCE84272) just fine for me. I also improved your pattern so that it doesn't consume the punctuation mark. It still splits just fine with the original pattern though.

Comment: @41686d6564 Ahaa I found the mistake. Thank you very much. Can you tell me how you improved the pattern so the punctuation mark isn't consumed?

Comment: By using a positive [Lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: Are you sure a linebreak is a ``\r\n`` pair, and not a standalone ``\n``? I recommend you replace regex ``\r\n`` with ``\R``, the [linebreak](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#lineending) pattern.

Comment: Yes, I think you may have newlines without carriage returns, simply make it optional should do the trick: `(\\.|؟|!)\\r?\\n` Code Demo: https://ideone.com/o3qDyc

Comment: If you process a file as text in python, the newlines will be `\n` only. Python automatically converts for you.

Comment: Perl has better unicode regex support than any other language.  Might be worth it to switch.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var pattern = "(\\.|\\?|\\!)(\\r\\n|\\r|\\n)";
    var text = """
            لودفيج فان بيتهوفن مؤلف موسيقي ألماني ولد عام 1770 م في مدينة بون. يعتبر من أبرز عباقرة الموسيقى في جميع العصور، وأبدع أعمالاً موسيقية خالدة. له الفضل الأعظم في تطوير الموسيقى الكلاسيكية. قدم أول عمل موسيقي وعمره 8 سنوات.
            تشمل مؤلفاته للأوركسترا تسـعة سيمفونيات وخمس مقطوعات موسيقية على البيانو ومقطوعة على الكمان. كما ألّف العديد من المقطوعات الموسيقية كمقدمات للأوبرا.
            بدأ بيتهوفن يفقد سمعه في الثلاثينيات من عمره إلا أن ذلك لم يؤثر على إنتاجه الذي ازداد في تلك الفترة وتميز بالإبداع. من أجمل أعماله السمفونية الخامسة والسادسة والتاسعة. وقد توفي في فيينا عام 1827م.
            شهدت مدينة بون الألمانية ميلاد الفنان العبقري لودفج فان بيتهوفن في 16 ديسمبر عام 1770، وتم تعميده في 17 ديسمبر 1770. ظهر تميزه الموسيقي منذ صغره، فنشرت أولى أعماله وهو في الثانية عشرمن عمره عام 1783 م. اتسعت شهرته كعازف بيانو في سن مبكرة، ثم زاد إنتاجه وذاع صيته كمؤلف موسيقى. عانى بيتهوفن كثيراً في حياته، عائلياً وصحياً، فبالرغم من أن أباه هو معلمه الأول الذي وجه اهتمامه للموسيقى ولقنه العزف على البيانو والكمان، إلا أنه لم يكن الأب المثالي، فقد كان مدمناً للكحول، كما أن والدته توفيت وهو في السابعة عشر من عمره بعد صراع طويل مع المرض، تاركة له مسؤولية العائلة. مما منعه من إتمام خطته والسفر إلى فيينا، عاصمة الموسيقى في ذلك العصر. فهل كان التأليف الموسيقي هو نوع من أنواع العلاج والتغلب على المشاكل بالنسبة لبيتهوفن.
            في 1789 م تحقق حلمه أخيراً، فقد أرسله حاكم بون إلى فيينا، وهناك تتلمذ على يد هايدن. ولكن بيتهوفن، صاحب الألحان واجه بعض الخلافات مع معلمه، وعندما سافر هايدن إلى لندن، تحول بيتهوفن إلى معلمين آخرين مثل ساليري وشينك وألبريشتبيرجر. وقد أسهمت كل هذه الدروس والاحتكاكات في تكوين شخصية بيتهوفن الفنية. وحاول أن يشق لنفسه طريق كعازف في عاصمة الموسيقى، وسرعان ما لاقى مكانة كبرى خاصة في الأوساط الأرستقراطية. فقد حاز بإعجاب الأسرة الملكية وعومل كصديق أكثر منه مؤلفاً. بالرغم من ذلك فقد عاش ومات فقيراً، غناه هو أعماله الفنية المتميزة. فقد جاء إنتاجه الفني غزيراً حتى بعد إصابته بالصمم.
            بدأت إصابة بيتهوفن بصمم بسيط عام 1802، فبدأ في الانسحاب من الأوساط الفنية تدريجياً، وأمضى حياته بلا زواج يرتبط بعلاقات عدة مع سيدات صغيرات. إلا أنه لم يتوقف عن الإنتاج الفني، ولكن أعماله اتخذت اتجاه جديد. ومع ازدياد حالة الصمم التي أصابته، امتنع عن العزف في الحفلات العامة، وابتعد عن الحياة الاجتماعية واتجه للوحدة، وقلت مؤلفاته، وأصبحت أكثر تعقيداً. حتى أنه رد على انتقادات نقاده بأنه يعزف للأجيال القادمة. وبالفعل مازالت أعماله حتى اليوم من أهم ما أنتجته الموسيقى الكلاسيكية العالمية. واكتسبت اثنان من السيمفونيات التي كتبها في صممه أكبر شعبية، وهما السيمفونية الخامسة والتاسعة. كما أنه أحدث الكثير من التغييرات في الموسيقى، وأدخل الغناء والكلمات في سيمفونيته التاسعة.فجاءت رسالته إلى العالم كل البشر سيصبحون إخوة.
            """;
    Arrays.stream(text.split(pattern)).forEach(line -> System.out.println(line +"\n##############################################\n"));
```